# How center align two equations separated by a line

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations

I wanted to center align two logical equations that do not use "=" sign. I also want to separate the equations with a line. Currently I use aligned environment and midrule. Can the equations be center aligned instead of right aligned? The minimum working example is given below:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{aligned}
        \forall_{t \in firing} \quad \forall_{a \in t \bullet} \quad a \in AN\\
        \midrule
        \mu^\prime_{an} = (\mu_{an} - \bullet t) \cup a, \quad c(a) = 0 \\
    \end{aligned}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What shall be aligned here actually? Wouldn't `alignat*` not better than a combination of `equation*` and `aligned`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - The OP may have used some unintentionally ambiguous terminology. Instead of "center aligned", it might be more felicitous to simply write "center".

Answer (score 5):

You could replace the `aligned` environment with a `gathered` environment, which centers its contents line by line.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    \begin{gathered} % 'gathered' instead of 'aligned'
        \forall_{t \in \textit{firing}} \quad \forall_{a \in t \bullet} \quad a \in AN\\
        \midrule
        \mu^\prime_{an} = (\mu_{an} - \bullet t) \cup a, \quad c(a) = 0 
    \end{gathered}
    \end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it works with gathered.

Answer (score 5):

I hope you understand your question. I add my MWE centering two logical equations without equal sign and separate the equations with a line.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,booktabs}
\begin{document}

$\begin{array}{@{}c@{}}
\forall_{t\in\mathit{firing}} \quad \forall_{a\in t\bullet} \quad a\in AN \\
\specialrule{.05em}{1em}{0em}\\
\mu'_{an} = (\mu_{an} - \bullet t) \cup a, \quad c(a) = 0 \\[.5em]
\specialrule{.2em}{.1em}{.1em} % optional
\end{array}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of using `\multicolumn{4}{c}{$...$}` for both rows, would it maybe be easier *not* to employ `\begin{tabular}{llll} ... \end{tabular}` and, instead, to employ `$\begin{array}{c} ... \end{array}$`?

Comment: You're right. When I entered the code I have not thought about it much. Compared much who is better than me. You can, if you like, change my code.

Comment: I've taken you up on the invitation to modify your code. Feel free to apply further changes.

Comment: @Mico Perfect. This way I learn new codes and shortcuts. Thanks a lot.